# Trying to read text file

Tags: c#

I have to read all lines of a text file to perform some some changements on it . 
My problem is that I didn't find how to read the path file :

```
string Source = Dts.Variables["User::VarFilesToMove"].Value.ToString();
string folder = Dts.Variables["$Project::FichierBanque"].Value.ToString() ;
string folderFtp = Dts.Variables["$Project::FtpFolderInLocation"].Value.ToString();
string file = folder  + Source + ".txt";
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"file");
//or string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("file");
//string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
```

Many thanks for any help .

Comment: Whats wrong with your last commented line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First to ensure that file exist. Try this

```
if (File.Exists(file))
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`file` is a `string` variable, just pass it to the method as parameter:

`string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);`